# Geometry problem with 2 circles and a triangle

Tags: geometry, circles

I tried to solve this problem:

> If $D$ is the diameter of the larger circle and $d$ is the diameter of the small circle, then $d+D$ equals
>
> (A) $a+b$   (B) $2(a+b)$   (C) $\sqrt{(a+b)}$   (D) $2\sqrt{ab}$   (E) $\sqrt{2(a^2+b^2)}$
>   [image]

---

But I did not know how to do it so I looked at the answers and I saw $E$ looked convincing because it is the only one that has square powers and $D$ (from the diagram) is $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ so I chose $E$. When I looked at the solutions, it said that $A$ was the answer and as I was reading the solutions. It said that I must drop perpendiculars from the center of the small circle to the sides of each triangle :[image]
That is what I assumed I must do. Then it said that the distance from the right angle to the points of contact is $\frac{1}{2}d$. Then it said that the distances from the other to angles to the points of contact are $a - \frac{1}{2}d + b-\frac{1}{2}d$. I don't understand this part, what does it mean? Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the ***sum of the*** distances from the other t***W***o angles to the points of contact

= red solid line (or the red dotted line) + green solid line (or the green dotted line)

= $(a - \frac{1}{2}d) + [b-\frac{1}{2}d]$

= $a - \frac{1}{2}d + b-\frac{1}{2}d$

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Adding a diagram made me understand.

Answer (score 1):

The bottom left corner of the triangle has a quadrilateral with every angle $90^{\circ}$ - a rectangle therefore. And you have two sides equal to $\frac d2$, so it is a square with side $\frac d2$. Mark all the sides of the square with $\frac d2$, and you should be able to see what is going on.

(Note that the triangle is right-angled because it is built on the diameter $D$- I note you haven't marked that known angle)